# MongoDB: Find a document that has all fields and value (except _id) equals of given document?

Tags: java, mongodb, database

Is there a way to search for documents whose all fields and values (except _id) are contained in given document fields?

Example:

```
{_id:..., "field1" : 2 , "field2" : 3}
{_id:..., "field1" : 2 , "field2" : 4}
{_id:..., "field1" : 2 , "field3" : 1}
```

document to place in the query:

```
{"field1" : 2 , "field2" : 4, "field3" : 1}
```

expected result:

```
{_id:..., "field1" : 2 , "field2" : 4}
{_id:..., "field1" : 2 , "field3" : 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below one should work. you can use [https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/](http://$or)

```
db.collection_name.find({"$or":[{"field1" : 2},{"field2" : 4},{"field3" : 1}]})
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not answer my question because the result for the query you wrote is all the documents of the example and not only the two expected.